# The options for communicating sensor data in a medium size building

Tags: sensor, communication

What are the options for communicating sensor data to a central point in a medium size building?

I want to build a cheap centralized temperature control. 
In each room there are about 4 radiators which I want to equip with a few sensors like temperature, light, sound level, and with a radiator valve actuator. Let's say the building has 50 rooms with a wireless network available.

The main requirements are low costs (for the project as a whole), and it should be relatively easy to design and implement. I have some experience with PCB design and micro controllers, and I can ask help of more experienced people.  I'm not bound to specific sensors or actuator.

I guess power for the sensors and for the actuator come from a power outlet. Maybe the signal can also travel over the power net.

P.S. As newbie, I feel I could use some help to improve this question. All help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain whats electronic knob ?

Comment: Have you worked on electronics projects before? This is quite ambitious, and will likely be relatively expensive.

Comment: @rahulb I found the word: radiator valve actuator.

Comment: @Polynomial I didn't do big projects before. If I go on with this I will ask help of an experienced engineer. First I would like to get a better idea of the options.

Comment: I think the added questions about sensors is beyond the scope of the original question and you'll probably get better answers raising this as a new question just focussing on  the sensors.

Comment: @Andyaka Thank you for your suggestion. I deleted the new questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Power line transmission is a good option for this. The chip-sets do seem to be able to handle "decent" data rates with a good degree of reliability. The 100kHz band looks probably the most attractive and is, as far as I know, dedicated to this sort of thing. [This](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&ved=0CHcQFjAH&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nxp.com%2Fdocuments%2Fapplication_note%2FAN10903.pdf&ei=NIUhU8auAY6whAf34ICoDw&usg=AFQjCNH_HJJ7nmf8khtZrFAVysYVuoS6BA&bvm=bv.62922401,d.ZG4) document from NXP (entitled AN10903, TDA5051A ASK power line modem) is a good reference for what you have to do. It contains a wealth of knowledge on how to couple to the AC lines and how to impedance match etc.. The chip-set is good for 1200baud and I think this would be good enough for what you are looking to achieve. Remember one thing, faster data rates = wider bandwidth = more received noise = less sensitive  receiver.

[Here](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nxp.com%2Fdocuments%2Fdata_sheet%2FTDA5051A.pdf&ei=a4chU-rCNsiHhQe1u4CIAg&usg=AFQjCNFZZUZ4CD5zthoz1J6IiJp-Md2F7Q&bvm=bv.62922401,d.ZG4) is the data sheet for the chip and below is a diagram in that document: -

[image]

Comment: This is an interesting option. Could you comment on the other hardware needed? I think at leas a microprocessor, right? And on the cost?

Comment: See also these links about the TDA5051A http://www.ukessays.com/essays/information-technology/a-low-cost-home-automation-system-information-technology-essay.php and http://www.digikey.com/en-US/articles/techzone/2011/mar/a-simple-costeffective-approach-to-home-automation

Comment: Other hardware? Not sure what you want to know other than they are fairly cheap and off-the-shelf parts used in the design and yes a small MCU is needed and then you'll need to consider the interface to the various sensors but to answer fully this becomes a mammoth task. Your 2nd comment mentions "these links" - I don't see any.

Comment: I see, that is all I wanted to know: this chip works with the cheapest sensors and the cheapest MCU's. TDA5051A costs about three dollars only, so this is a good option.

Comment: @sjdh 1200bps is not too slow for you? Bear in mind that you will need to packetize data into a frame that would need to have an error checking and data repeat request functionality to ensure things are not switching on and off randomly - this is why these things can be so troublesome but it's the same for radio!!

Comment: @Anday aka How about this calculation: 50 rooms * 4 radiators * 5 sensors functions = 1000 sensors. Say effectively 100 b/s of real (sensor) information is left. Average sensor info of 100 bits. Then each sensor can be read every 1000 seconds= 17 min. Seems to be over the limit indeed. But maybe there are only about 10 rooms sharing one group of the electricity net.

Comment: @sjdh 1 sensor will have probably an 8-bit value or maybe 16-bit at most. Say 16 bits/sensor. That's 16,000 bits in total and assume real data payload is 50% of 1200bpsec = 600bps. 16,000 bits divided by 600 = less than 30 seconds turnaround time.

Comment: @Anday aka Then it will do.